# How to get email notifications from email client?

Tags: android

Is there any programmatic way to get email notification in my application from the built in android email client? Do I have to write my own email client if I want to add custom features like auto-reply and stuffs like it or I can extend some notification framework from any existing application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any programmatic way to get email notification in my application from the built in android email client?

Which "built in android email client"? Across all Android devices, there is more than one "android email client" programs that are "built in".

If you are referring to the Email application from the Android open source project, it has no documented APIs or broadcasts.

> Do I have to write my own email client
>   if I want to add custom features like
>   auto-reply and stuffs like it or I can
>   extend some notification framework
>   from any existing application?

You are welcome to add those features to open source email clients, or to convince those email clients to expose enough hooks to allow you to add those features as a third-party application.

Comment: yes, I was referencing to the email application of opensource android project. I tried to build the music application from source without much success. I think I need the whole android platform to build it. Is it same for the email client also?

Comment: @Sajid: Yes, if you wish to rebuild any of the AOSP applications, you need to build them as part of firmware. Many were written before the SDK existed.